# How to know if an attribute contains non letters characters in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function that should retire all the non string characters, the logic of the function is that i passed a string as parameter and in the if compares if there is any strange character inside the passed attribute if this is true returns an error and if is not return the attribute ,that is what it should do, but i'm having problems when doing this

I'm using an ADT structure and my function is for validate inserts from my ADT type

***This is my ADT, where i define my attributes***

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE datos_basicos_personas AS OBJECT(
    primer_nombre varchar(15),
    STATIC FUNCTION valida_primer_nombre(primer_nombre varchar) RETURN varchar
);
```

***Function that should returns the attribute if doesn't contains non string characters***

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY datos_basicos_personas IS
STATIC FUNCTION valida_primer_nombre(primer_nombre varchar) RETURN varchar
IS
BEGIN 
    IF regexp_like(primer_nombre, '^[a-zA-Z]') THEN
        return (primer_nombre);
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: El Primer nombre debe contener solo letras.');
    END IF;
END;
END;
```

***My table, that has one attribute of my ADT type(datos_basicos_personas)***

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persona (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    datos_basicos datos_basicos_personas
);
```

***Insert, my insert has a 9 number it shouldn't let me do the insert ***

```sql
INSERT INTO Persona values (2,datos_basicos_personas(datos_basicos_personas.valida_primer_nombre('H9ilery')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `CHECK` constraint in which whether a non-letter character exists in the string to violate the rule through a regular expression such as

```
CREATE TABLE Persona (
    id            INT PRIMARY KEY,
    datos_basicos VARCHAR2(15),
    CONSTRAINT chk_datos_basicos CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(datos_basicos,'^[[:alpha:]]+$') ) 
);
```

In this case posix `[:alpha]` is used within `REGEXP_LIKE()` to check the violating character until the end of the word( by `+$`).